# Hide opened menu after orientation change android

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

In my application, there is requirement to show different menus on portrait and landscape mode.

This I have achieved using calling invalidateOptionsMenu() in onCreate(); and then I check orientation in onCreateOptionsMenu().

**Problem**

If I open options menu on portrait mode and change orientation, this menu item remains open in landscape mode.

**Current Implementation:**

Android handles this orientation change, so my activity recreates after change in orientation.

**Options I have tried**

1. Called closeOptionsMenu() in onDestroy().
2. Called closeOptionsMenu() in onSaveInstanceState().
3. Called Moved my code in onCreateOptionsMenu() to onPrepareOptionsMenu().

Please advise.

Thanks,